# Is it impossible that $(X,Y)$ follows bivariate normal if they always have the same sign?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, multivariate-statistical-analysis

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ follows normal distribution respectively.
I heard that if $X$ and $Y$ always have the same sign, then $(X,Y)$ cannot follow the bivariate normal distribution.
However, I can't see why. Any explanation please?

Comment: It is necessary to state what kind of objects X and Y are. Are they perhaps random variables?  And there are many bivariate normal distributions. Are you thinking of the standard one? Or an arbitrary one?

Comment: If two normal variables X and Y are such that every realization of X and Y have the same sign then one should be able to prove that they are perfectly correlated $\rho=1$. But then the pdf of the bivariate normal is not well defined. I think one should be able to proof that $X=\alpha \cdot Y$ for some $\alpha >0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bivariate normal distribution, as commonly understood, is a joint distribution  with a *density function* $f(x,y)$ that is strictly positive for all values of $x$ and $y$. The probability that $X$ and $Y$ have opposite sign is $P(X>0, Y<0) + P(X<0, Y>0)$, which will be positive since you are integrating a strictly positive joint density over the regions $(0,\infty)\times(-\infty,0)$ and $(-\infty,0)\times(0,\infty)$. So there is always a chance, albeit possibly tiny, that $X$ and $Y$ have opposite sign when $(X,Y)$ have bivariate normal distribution.

There is one situation where $X$ and $Y$ always have the same sign: when $X$ and $Y$ are equal to each other, i.e., $Y$ and $X$ are names for the same variable. But in that situation the joint distribution is "singular" and doesn't possess a density, and people regard this situation as a degenerate case.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution seems to  say $(Z,Z)$ is jointly normal when $Z\sim N(0,1)$, tho.

Comment: @kimchilover Right, and Wikipedia declares $AX+b$ to be jointly normal for any matrix $A$ and vector $X$ of standard normals.  It wasn't clear from the OP whether the concept of bivariate normal requires a density, or whether it admits singular distributions.